# The output of predictions on Python

Tags: python

Library Selection

```
import numpy as np
import keras as k
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
```

The main block of the program

```
train_x = np.array([-4.2,-7.1,-9.1,5.2,10.4,17.4,17.9,16.8,12.2,3.9,-1.2,-5.9,-10.4,-15.6,-2.6,7.2,11.6,19.2,19.0,17.3,10.0,5.8,-3.2,-5.6,-14.3,-14.0,-6.0,-1.8,-6.3,6.6,14.4,15.2,18.6,17.1,12.4,5.2,-0.9,-4.6,-7.0,-7.7,-6.0,4.1,13.3,14.9,18.4,15.7,9.1,6.0,-0.8,-7.6,-4.4,-5.5,-1.4,6.6,11.5,16.9,20.6,16.9,8.2,2.2,-5.1,-11.0,-9.4,-7.6,-5.5,5.0,11.6,18.5,21.0,16.2,9.8,2.3,-3.6,0.2,-6.2,-2.4,0.2,4.3,12.1,19.2,19.4,16.8,9.7,6.6,-1.6,-8.1,-4.2,-6.1,-5.0,7.6,13.2,13.5,16.4,14.8,10.8,6.4,1.4,-7.4,-15.9,-10.0,-9.4,3.9,17.0,13.5,19.1,17.8,13.2,5.6,-0.2,-8.8,-8.1,-10.0,-6.2,4.2,11.5,19.0,20.0,16.0,11.8,6.9,-2.3,-2.9,-9.6,-10.1,-3.3,2.5,9.7,16.0,16.7,15.8,12.9,3.8,-5.8,-1.5,-9.7,-8.9,0.0,8.7,15.4,16.5,19.2,16.6,9.5,6.1,-0.9,-10.5,-13.9,-10.4,0.3,6.0,12.4,18.3,15.7,17.7,10.8,3.0,-2.5,-5.3,-16.2,-13.4,-6.9,6.0,11.1,14.7,17.8,16.4,10.2,4.7,1.8,-9.2,-10.4,-8.3,-2.9,5.8,12.6,15.8,19.3,16.3,11.1,5.4,-1.8,-5.9,-3.5,-9.4,-4.2,3.8,12.8,16.4,17.5,16.7,10.8,3.2,-0.6,-5.7,-14.9,-7.4,-2.5,5.9,12.6,19.0,22.4,20.6,11.0,5.2,-0.2,-0.9,-10.2,-3.4,-1.0,7.9,13.3,18.2,18.0,15.9,7.6,3.8,-2.1,-5.9,-10.2,-1.5,-0.6,3.4,9.6,16.4,18.2,15.9,13.1,8.7,1.8,-2.3,-3.7,-6.4,1.2,10.1,15.6,17.8,18.5,15.0,13.7,4.1,-3.3,-4.0,-12.2,-11.4,-2.6,5.7,10.9,13.7,16.1,14.5,9.6,-1.0,-0.8,-3.7,-11.2,-6.3,-0.9,7.0,14.2,16.8,18.8,15.8,9.5,3.1,1.7,-8.2,-7.3,-9.5,0.4,4.6,10.5,14.3,16.3,15.8,9.7,3.3,2.0,-14.5,-9.9,-8.8,-0.9,3.3,17.1,17.2,16.7,16.9,11.7,3.8,-0.9,-5.7,-11.3,-7.1,-6.4,5.8,8.4,17.9,17.2,14.7,10.5,5.2,-2.0,-4.2,-5.4,-4.9,-3.1,3.3,14.0,19.8,21.5,17.4,10.8,7.8,-0.6,-3.5,-10.1,-8.8,-0.7,5.3,12.0,13.8,18.4,16.6,11.8,4.1,2.0,-1.1,-4.0,-6.9,-1.4,9.3,15.6,14.5,17.9,16.0,12.4,6.2,-1.5,-3.2,-4.4,-10.3,-2.3,7.5,16.0,15.6,17.6,15.1,12.4,6.8,-3.5,-9.6,-10.0,-14.0,-3.1,5.4,13.0,14.6,16.4,19.4,10.1,6.1,-3.3,-6.5,-6.7,-13.5,0.2,6.7,13.6,18.6,17.8,16.5,8.6,4.2,-0.1,-7.5,-17.5,-6.0,-5.3,2.8,12.8,17.7, 16.8,15.1,9.0,3.6,-3.6,-7.0,-7.2,-6.1,-1.0,5.3,13.8,19.5,21.6,16.5,11.3,4.9,-4.4,-6.9,-2.1,-0.5,2.0,7.7,13.4,20.0,19.2,16.2,12.2,5.3,-2.6,-5.3,-5.7,0.4,2.0,8.1,10.8,14.5,17.5,16.0,9.3,5.3,0.2,-3.4,-6.2,-6.7,-1.2,7.0,13.4,18.8,18.1,16.1,11.0,6.5,1.0,-4.0,-4.4,-10.3,-2.3,7.5,16.0,15.6,17.6,15.1,12.4,6.8,-3.5,-9.6,-10.0,-14.0,-3.1,5.4,13.0,14.6,16.4,19.4,10.1,6.1,-3.3,-6.5,-6.7,-13.5,0.2,6.7,13.6,18.6,17.8,16.5,8.6,4.2,-0.1,-7.5,-17.5,-6.0,-5.3,2.8,12.8,17.7,16.8,15.1,9.0,3.6,-3.6,-7.0,-7.2,-6.1,-1.0,5.3,13.8,19.5,21.6,16.5,11.3,4.9,-4.4,-6.9,-2.1,-0.5,2.0,7.7,13.4,20.0,19.2,16.2,12.2,5.3,-2.6,-5.3,-5.7,0.4,2.0,8.1,10.8,14.5,17.5,16.0,9.3,5.3,0.2,-3.4,-6.2,-6.7,-1.2,7.0,13.4,18.8,18.1,16.1,11.0,6.5,1.0,-4.0,-5.3,-4.3,1.6,5.1,11.9,16.7,18.6,18.0,13.1,2.2,-2.5,-4.4,-4.4,-4.9,-1.9,5.7,14.5,14.0,17.5,15.4,6.9,4.6,-8.0,-3.6,-3.4,-11.3,-2.9,7.2,9.8,14.5,17.6,15.9,13.7,5.0,-2.5,-7.9,-5.9,-0.8,0.6,9.1,14.5,19.7,17.5,16.8,12.8,6.7,-2.8,-9.5,-10.0,-9.7,-3.0,6.4,15.7,16.5,18.9,17.3,9.9,6.0,3.9,-7.0,-7.7,-4.7,-0.9,4.6,11.1,17.9,18.7,17.1,8.5,3.7,-0.8,-7.5,-4.7,-7.6,-1.3,3.9,13.7,20.0,18.9,15.5,10.7,5.6,-8.0,-5.9,-4.6,-6.2,-0.8,9.7,8.7,21.4,21.7,16.4,11.8,7.4,-4.9,-1.7,-6.1,-2.7,0.7,11.1,10.8,16.2,19.3,16.7,10.0,7.2,-0.1,-2.6,-4.3,-7.2,-2.1,11.0,11.2,16.3,23.0,17.0,12.2,4.8,-0.5,-10.6,-4.8,-0.4,2.2,7.2,12.7,17.3,22.6,17.0,12.0,2.6,-1.5,-12.6,-7.3,-8.6,-2.7,4.7,15.5,12.8,20.6,16.9,11.3,5.6,1.1,-2.1,-6.5,-7.0,1.3,4.6,11.4,15.3,19.0,18.4,12.1,5.9,-1.6,-2.9,-3.0,-8.9,-6.0,7.1,14.8,16.5,19.3,17.6,13.1,6.0,1.4,-4.1,-10.8,-13.3,-3.7,6.0,12.4,18.2,18.0,17.5,13.3,7.0,0.7,1.2,-1.6,-11.0,4.4,5.8,15.9,17.4,18.9,20.2,11.8,7.0,-2.0,-2.0,-5.8,-1.5,1.8,9.4,11.3,15.6,19.1,17.5,10.9,8.9,2.3,-1.8,-5.6,-5.4,-0.6,5.1,13.6,17.3,18.8,15.6,13.8,5.8,2.2,-6.5,-14.5,-8.4,-1.1,8.3,16.7,18.8,26.0,21.8,11.7,3.8,2.7,-7.6,-7.5,-11.0,-2.0,6.4,14.6,19.0, 23.4,18.7,12.1,6.6,0.2,-0.1,-6.8,-11.7,-3.1,8.2,15.1,17.1,20.9,17.7,12.9,6.5,1.6,-8.6,-8.5,-3.5,-6.5,6.1,16.9,19.8,18.9,18.3,10.3,6.6,4.0,-1.7,-8.6,-1.9,2.8,7.0,16.0,16.1,21.1,19.2,12.3,3.7,-1.3,-3.9,-4.4,-2.2,2.0,6.1,14.2,17.9,18.3,17.6,13.8,4.4,0.8,0.2,-10.1,-0.6,0.3,8.1,15.0,18.2,20.9,19.5,11.4,4.4,-2.7,-4.6,7.8,-4.6,2])
train_y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
print("raw data shape: ", train_x.shape, train_y.shape)
# Reshape data

train_x = train_x.astype(np.float32).reshape(1, 833, -1)
train_y = train_y.astype(np.float32).reshape(1, 840, -1)

# make sure train_x and train_y are shaped same
train_y = train_y[:, :train_x.shape[1], :]

print("properly reshaped data: ", train_x.shape, train_y.shape)
input_shape = (train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[0])
print("input shape: ", input_shape)
print("\n")
# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='tanh', input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()
# Train the model
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=228)
```

Part of the output program ( it knows the error )

```
predictions = model.predict(train_x)[-12:]

for _ in range(12):
    next_values = np.concatenate((last_values[:, 1:, :], predictions[:, np.newaxis, :]), axis=1)
    predictions = np.append(predictions, model.predict(next_values[:, -12:, :]), axis=1)

predicted_values = predictions.flatten()

print("result: ")
for value in predicted_values[-12:]:
    print(value)
```

The error give in the line:

```
    next_values = np.concatenate((last_values[:, 1:, :], predictions[:, np.newaxis, :]), axis=1)
```

The error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d32bfe82c9e0> in <cell line: 3>()
      2 
      3 for _ in range(12):
----> 4     next_values = np.concatenate((last_values[:, 1:, :], predictions[:, np.newaxis, :]), axis=1)
      5     predictions = np.append(predictions, model.predict(next_values[:, -12:, :]), axis=1)
      6 

NameError: name 'last_values' is not defined
```

How fixing this? And one quastion this is decision?

```
predictions = model.predict(train_x)[-12:]
last_values = train_x[-1]

for _ in range(12):
    next_values = np.concatenate((last_values[:, 1:, :], predictions[:, np.newaxis, :]), axis=1)
    predictions = np.append(predictions, model.predict(next_values[:, -12:, :]), axis=1)

predicted_values = predictions.flatten()

print("resuly work: ")
for value in predicted_values[-12:]:
    print(value)
```

Comment: You did not define the variable `last_values` but try to use it.

Comment: I rewrote the program a bit, but it still doesn't work. I left the rewritten version at the very end. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```py
last_values = train_x[:, -12:, :]
```

I assume you want to use the last 12 entries in the train data, but what you are doing is taking all entries (which is only one), and using only the last 12 features of that entry. And your model expects 833 features per entry.

As `train_x` has the shape (1,833,1) I am not sure, what you want to achieve with the `-12:`. What are you trying to select?

Edit:
If you want to get the last values of your prediction you should, instead of using

```py
last_values = train_x[-12:, :, :]
predictions = model.predict(last_values)
```

just use

```py
predictions = model.predict(train_x)[-12:]
```

Comment: No this is not working they give new error 
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 4 dimension(s)

Comment: You have to change one line as shown in my answer. What do you mean with full code?

Comment: At first I didn't understand where, but unfortunately a new error appeared, but thanks for the hint

Comment: To be honest, I'm trying to predict the weather and trying to output the last 12 values

Comment: Does my updated anwser help you?

Comment: No, but this gave me another error, I updated the question for a new error.